# Replacing an attribute from within a tag

Tags: validation, tags, xss

Consider this:

```
<img style="INFO" alt="INFO" src="INFO" target="INFO" onmouseout="INFO" />
```

How can I target every attribute (style, alt, src etc.) within the IMG tag to validate it against a white-list?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DOM parser for that. Depending on what language you are using there are different library that you can use for that.